# Car chase trajectory and time

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

I Cannot figure out this problem.(it is in 2d)

> There are 2 cars. 1st car is chasing second car. Car1 has starting
>   position (2,4) and speed of 5(coordinates per second). Car2 has
>   position of (16,20) moving in at speed of 2(coordinates per second) at
>   an angle of 60(degrees)(angle is relative to x axis).
>
> What angle does car1 need to choose and how long is it will take to
>   chase car2?

Should I use vectors? Because for me it looks like impossible to solve it

I know hot to solve this question for 1 dimension but I cannot figure it for 2 dimensions.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use vectors? Also, "angle of 60" relative to what? The line connecting Car1 and Car2? The x-axis?

Comment: Ignore my comment. I can't read.

Comment: the angle is relative to x axis

Comment: The 2D case works like 2 1D cases, except that you do not know Car1's speed in x-direction or Car1's speed in y-direction, only a combination of both, which gives you a system of 2 equations to transform and insert into a third one, ultimately solving a quadratic equation, no matter whether you derive them from a vector-based approach, coordinates, or else. Again, what did you try?

Comment: I have not tried a lot. I actually had no idea how to do it. But the simultaneous equation idea sounds good it might just work, I will try it.

Comment: Tried simultaneous equations. Gets to messy or I do not know how to do it. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Write the position of car 2 as a function of $t$.  You can use trig to get the velocity in each $x$ and $y$ directions.  Now assume car 1 travels at angle $\theta$.  You can use trig to get its $x$ and $y$ velocity, then get its position as a function of $t$.  These two positions must be equal.  You get one equation from each coordinate, and have two unknowns:  $t, \theta$, so can solve for both.

Comment: i tried this but the end equation ends impossible to solve. with sin and cos

Comment: You have $14+t\sqrt 3=5t\cos \theta, 16+t=5t\sin \theta$  If you square and add, the $\theta$'s disappear and you have a quadratic in $t$

Comment: Did not think of that. Thanks a bunch ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not consider this an answer to the mathematical question, but an extended comment for programmers on how to implement the solution as a computer program.

You can consider this is a shameless rip-off from the [answer by Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/681031/318422), rewritten for programmers implementing solutions to this type of problem, with a few practical details and suggestions sprinkled in.

---

In a computer program, to represent a 2D point moving at fixed speed in a fixed direction, it is best to use
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = x_0 + t x_v \\
y(t) = y_0 + t y_v \\
\end{cases} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
because the vector algebra solution without trigonometric functions is easier to implement, and on typical current hardware, faster as well (because trigonometric functions are "slow" compared to addition, multiplication, and division, on most hardware architectures).

If the point is at $(x_{t_0}, y_{t_0})$ at time $t = t_0$, with speed $v$ and direction $\varphi$ (from origin, $\varphi = 0\text{°} = 360\text{°}$ is towards $+x$, $\varphi = 90\text{°} = -270\text{°}$ is towards $+y$, $\varphi = 180\text{°} = -180\text{°}$ is towards $-x$, and $\varphi = 270\text{°} = -90\text{°}$ is towards $-y$), then
$$\begin{cases}
x_0 = x_{t_0} - t_0 v \cos\varphi \\
y_0 = y_{t_0} - t_0 v \sin\varphi \\
x_v = v \cos\varphi \\
y_v = v \sin\varphi \\
\end{cases} \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
In other words, using $\eqref{NA1}$ does not mean we cannot *define* the point trajectories using (angular) direction and speed; it is just that internally, you'll want to use the vector form.

Let's say that we know $\eqref{NA1}$ for some target, and wish to intercept it with a point that starts at $(X_T , Y_0T$ at time $t = T$, with constant speed $V$. Mathematically, for our projectile, we have
$$\begin{cases}
X(t) = X_T + (t - T) X_v \\
Y(t) = Y_T + (t - T) Y_v \\
X_v^2 + Y_v^2 = V^2
\end{cases}$$
and we need to solve for $t$, $X_v$, and $Y_v$ from
$$\bbox{\begin{cases}
X(t) = x(t) \\
Y(t) = y(t) \\
X_v^2 + Y_v^2 = v^2
\end{cases}} \quad \iff \quad \bbox{\begin{cases}
X_0 - x_0 + t (X_v - x_v) - t_0 X_v = 0 \\
Y_0 - y_0 + t (Y_v - y_v) - t_0 Y_v = 0 \\ 
X_v^2 + Y_v^2 = v^2
\end{cases}}$$

In practice, it is best to solve for $t$ first. For the interception to be possible, we obviously only care about solutions where $t \ge T$, since we cannot fire backwards in time; and a solution $t = T$ means the target intercepts the projectile starting point $(X_T , Y_T)$ at time $t = T$.

There are two cases we need to handle separately:

1. Target and projectile speeds are equal, $x_v^2 + y_v^2 = V^2$.

   First, calculate
   $$\bbox{d = T (x_v^2 + y_v^2) - x_v (X_T - x_0) - y_v (Y_T - y_0) }$$
   If $d = 0$, interception is not possible.

   Otherwise, calculate
   $$\bbox{t = \frac{T^2 (x_v^2 + y_v^2) - (X_T - x_0)^2 - (Y_T - y_0)^2}{2 d}}$$
   If $t \le T$, interception is not possible.
2. Target and projectile velocities differ, $x_v^2 + y_v^2 \ne V^2$.

   First, calculate
   $$\bbox{ r = V^2 \bigr( (T x_v + x_0 - X_T)^2 + (T y_v + y_0 - Y_T)^2 \bigr) - \bigr( x_v (y_0 - Y_T) - y_v (x_0 - X_T) \bigr)^2 }$$
   If $r \le 0$, interception is not possible.

   Then, calculate
   $$\bbox{ \begin{aligned}
   s &= T V^2 + x_v ( x_0 - X_T ) + y_v ( y_0 - Y_T) \\
   d &= V^2 - x_v^2 - y_v^2 \\
   \end{aligned} }$$
   and finally
   $$\bbox{ \begin{aligned}
   t_1 &= \frac{s + \sqrt{r}}{d} \\
   t_2 &= \frac{s - \sqrt{r}}{d} \\
   \end{aligned} }$$
   If both $t_1 \le T$ and $t_2 \le T$, intersection is not possible.
   If both $t_1 \gt T$ and $t_2 \gt T$, set $t = \min( t_1 , t_2 )$.
   Otherwise, set $t = t_1$ if $t_1 \gt T$; or $t = t_2$ if $T_2 \gt T$.

At this point, we have the time of the interception $t \gt T$ if interception is indeed possible. Then, the velocity vector $(X_V , Y_V)$ for that interception is
$$\bbox{ \begin{cases}
\displaystyle X_V = \frac{x_0 - X_T + t x_v}{t - T} \\
\displaystyle Y_V = \frac{y_0 - Y_T + t y_v}{t - T} \\
\end{cases} }$$
If the interception time $t$ was computed as above, you'll find that $X_V^2 + Y_V^2 = V^2$, to within rounding error.

Here is an example implementation in Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#
# Public domain. Written by Nominal Animal; no warranties, no guarantees.
#
import math
import sys

class MovingPoint(tuple):
    """2D point moving in a constant direction at a constant velocity"""

    def __new__(cls, xt, yt, t=0, xv=None, yv=None, speed=None, direction=None):
        if (speed is not None) and (direction is not None):
            angle = float(direction) * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0
            xv = float(speed) * math.cos(angle)
            yv = float(speed) * math.sin(angle)
        else:
            if xv is None:
                xv = 0.0
            if yv is None:
                yv = 0.0

        x0 = float(xt) - float(t)*xv
        y0 = float(yt) - float(t)*yv

        return super().__new__(cls, (x0, y0, xv, yv))

    @property
    def speed(self):
        """Speed"""
        return math.sqrt(self[2]*self[2] + self[3]*self[3])

    @property
    def direction(self):
        """Direction in degrees"""
        return math.atan2(self[3], self[2]) * 180.0 / 3.14159265358979323846

    @property
    def x0(self):
        """X coordinate at time t=0"""
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y0(self):
        """Y coordinate at time t=0"""
        return self[1]

    @property
    def xv(self):
        """Velocity vector x component"""
        return self[2]

    @property
    def yv(self):
        """Velocity vector y component"""
        return self[3]

    @property
    def p0(self):
        """Location at time t=0"""
        return (self[0], self[1])

    @property
    def v(self):
        """Velocity vector"""
        return (self[2], self[3])

    def x(self, t):
        """X coordinate as a function of time"""
        return self[0] + float(t) * self[2]

    def y(self, t):
        """Y coordinate as a function of time"""
        return self[1] + float(t) * self[3]

    def p(self, t):
        """Location as a function of time"""
        return (self[0] + float(t) * self[2], self[1] + float(t) * self[3])

def intercept(mpoint, xt, yt, t, v):
    """Calculate interception to MovingPoint mpoint.
       Returns None if no intersection, tuple (t, xv, yv) otherwise."""

    x0, y0, xv, yv = mpoint.x0, mpoint.y0, mpoint.xv, mpoint.yv
    xt, yt, t, v = float(xt), float(yt), float(t), float(v)

    mvv = xv*xv + yv*yv
    vv = v*v

    if mvv == vv:
        d = t*mvv - xv*(xt - x0) - yv*(yt - y0)
        if d == 0.0:
            return None
        it = (t*t * mvv - (xt - x0)**2 - (yt - y0)**2) / (2*d)
        if it <= t:
            return None
    else:
        r = vv*( (t*xv + x0 - xt)**2 + (t*yv + y0 - yt)**2 ) - ( xv*(y0 - yt) - yv*(x0 - xt) )**2
        if r <= 0:
            return None
        r = math.sqrt(r)

        s = t*vv + xv*(x0 - xt) + yv*(y0 - yt)
        d = vv - mvv
        t1 = (s + r) / d
        t2 = (s - r) / d

        if t1 > t and t2 > t:
            it = min(t1, t2)
        elif t1 > t:
            it = t1
        elif t2 > t:
            it = t2
        else:
            return None

    vx = (x0 - xt + it*xv) / (it - t)
    vy = (y0 - yt + it*yv) / (it - t)

    return (it, vx, vy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 9:
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s [ -h | --help | help ]\n" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.stderr.write("       %s x0 y0 xv yv  XT YT T V\n" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    x0 = float(sys.argv[1])
    y0 = float(sys.argv[2])
    xv = float(sys.argv[3])
    yv = float(sys.argv[4])
    sys.stderr.write("Target: x(0)=%.6f, y(0)=%.6f, xv=%.6f, yv=%.6f\n" % (x0, y0, xv, yv))

    xt = float(sys.argv[5])
    yt = float(sys.argv[6])
    t  = float(sys.argv[7])
    v  = float(sys.argv[8])
    sys.stderr.write("Interceptor: x(%.6f)=%.6f, y(%.6f)=%.6f, speed=%.6f\n" % (t, xt, t, yt, v))

    target = MovingPoint(x0, y0, xv=xv, yv=yv)
    icept = intercept(target, xt, yt, t, v)
    if icept is None:
        sys.stderr.write("Interception is not possible.\n")
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("Interception occurs at time %.6f, using xv=%.6f, yv=%.6f\n" % icept)
        bullet = MovingPoint(xt, yt, t=t, xv=icept[1], yv=icept[2])
        sys.stdout.write("#time  target_x target_y  interceptor_x interceptor_y\n")
        N = 20
        t0 = min(t, 0.0)
        prevtau = t0 - 1
        for i in range(0, N+1):
            tau = ((N-i)*t0 + i*icept[0]) / N

            if prevtau < t and tau > t:
                sys.stdout.write("%.6f   %.6f %.6f   %.6f %.6f\n" % (t, target.x(t), target.y(t), bullet.x(t), bullet.y(t)))
            elif prevtau < 0 and tau > 0:
                sys.stdout.write("%.6f   %.6f %.6f   %.6f %.6f\n" % (0, target.x(0), target.y(0), bullet.x(0), bullet.y(0)))
            prevtau = tau

            if tau < t:
                sys.stdout.write("%.6f   %.6f %.6f\n" % (tau, target.x(tau), target.y(tau)))
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("%.6f   %.6f %.6f   %.6f %.6f\n" % (tau, target.x(tau), target.y(tau), bullet.x(tau), bullet.y(tau)))
```

The `MovingPoint` class implements a 2D point that moves in a constant direction at constant speed. The `intercept()` function computes an interception trajectory.

If you run the above program using e.g. `python3 intercept.py 1.00 3.25 0.5 0.3  8.00 -4.00  5.5 0.85`, we test if we can hit a target $x(t) = 1.00 + 0.5 t$, $y(t) = 3.25 + 0.3 t$, with a projectile that starts at $x(5.5) = 8.00$, $y(5.5) = -4.00$, with velocity $0.85$.  The output is

```
Target: x(0)=1.000000, y(0)=3.250000, xv=0.500000, yv=0.300000
Interceptor: x(5.500000)=8.000000, y(5.500000)=-4.000000, speed=0.850000
Interception occurs at time 22.935375, using xv=0.256243, yv=0.810456
#time  target_x target_y  interceptor_x interceptor_y
0.000000   1.000000 3.250000
1.146769   1.573384 3.594031
2.293538   2.146769 3.938061
3.440306   2.720153 4.282092
4.587075   3.293538 4.626123
5.500000   3.750000 4.900000   8.000000 -4.000000
5.733844   3.866922 4.970153   8.059921 -3.810480
6.880613   4.440306 5.314184   8.353772 -2.881074
8.027381   5.013691 5.658214   8.647623 -1.951667
9.174150   5.587075 6.002245   8.941474 -1.022261
10.320919   6.160459 6.346276   9.235325 -0.092855
11.467688   6.733844 6.690306   9.529176 0.836551
12.614456   7.307228 7.034337   9.823028 1.765957
13.761225   7.880613 7.378368   10.116879 2.695363
14.907994   8.453997 7.722398   10.410730 3.624769
16.054763   9.027381 8.066429   10.704581 4.554176
17.201531   9.600766 8.410459   10.998432 5.483582
18.348300   10.174150 8.754490   11.292283 6.412988
19.495069   10.747534 9.098521   11.586134 7.342394
20.641838   11.320919 9.442551   11.879985 8.271800
21.788607   11.894303 9.786582   12.173837 9.201206
22.935375   12.467688 10.130613   12.467688 10.130613
```

which tells us that yes, it is possible, using $x_v = 0.256243$ and $y_v = 0.810456$ ($\sqrt{x_v^2 + y_v^2} = 0.85$ as specified), in which case the intercept occurs at $(12.467688, 10.130613)$ at time $t = 22.935375$.

If you redirect the output to a file, you can plot the trajectories using `plot "file" u 2:3 t "target" w linespoints, "file" u 4:5 t "interceptor" w linespoints`.